# How to strip the comments off the jsp view?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, servlet-filters

I need a mechanism that remove my comments from view, something like a filter in `web.xml`. It is better if this filter works on every files(e.g. javascript,css, ...) not only JSPs.
comment sample in JSP file :

```
<script>
    //var time = null;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **JtidyFilter** by setting hide-comments to true.This will strip HTML comments out of a page generated with JSP/JSTL.

http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/multiproject/jtidyservlet/filter.html

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>config</param-name>
    <param-value>hide-comments: true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Are you sure about your filter config? Is it getting called ?

Comment: Yes surely it is called, but it misbehaves and comments out so many elements.

Comment: besieds, I need it to be on maven repository.